# Android Studio - Dart Code formatting problems

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I've been trying different configurations in the code-formatting settings from Android-Studio, but the results have been pretty disappointing (and triggering) so far.

This is what the `reformat code` does without the `dartfmt` tool (notice line 94 - 110):
[image]

`dartfmt` does a better job of it, but the indentation is horrible (line 91 - 96) and very inconsistent with seemingly no settings to configure for it:
[image]

This is what I would want it to look like:
[image]

What settings do I need to change to achieve this? It's currently pretty hard to read the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deeply nested code is quite challenging to format and when the remaining space in lines become too short dartformat unindents to be able to format the rest of the code better.

It's better to avoid deeply nested code and instead refactor parts into their own function/method or if it is a Flutter build method, into widgets.

If you still think the behavior is invalid, please create an issue in dart-lang/dart_style and the maintainer will very likely respond with a profound answer.

Comment: I'm surprised that the internal formatter isn't able to properly format it either though, considering it has always worked for Java and PHP.

But I guess there's not much else to it then

Comment: Uh, Java is so long in the past. There were no closures back then. No idea if you could write comparable code now in Java. As mentioned, if you want a more profound answer, create an issue. Bob usually explains what rules are at play and what tradeoffs were accepted for what reason. He's a bit swamped lately though, so no promises.

Answer (score 11):

You can't configure `dartfmt`. This is voluntary. But `dartfmt` uses trailing comma as it's core to determine where to go to newline.

The following :

```
foo({String foo, String bar}) {}

void main() {
  foo(foo: "Hello", bar: "Hello");
}
```

will stay unchanged when running `dartfmt`.

But simply changing to `foo` call to :

```
  ...bar: "Hello",);
```

will reformat it to :

```
foo({String foo, String bar}) {}

void main() {
  foo(
    foo: "Hello",
    bar: "Hello",
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the indentation of `dartfmt` being very inconsistent

Comment: Because the output you desire can be achieved by adding a trailing comma where you didn't put one

Comment: line 91 - 96 doesn't really have any code where a trailing comma can be placed. And I want the indentation to always be 4 spaces, not sometimes 4 and sometimes 2

Comment: You can't change such thing. But this will solve your problem with parenthesis

Answer (score 7):

It is too late but it can help.

In Android Studio go to

**File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Dart**

and increase the value of Line Length.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an Android Developer and cannot leave Android Studio, since it's your coding home, but can't let go of flutter either.

**Changing tab size won't work through `Default.xml` in `codestyles`.**

**Use a different theme: Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme** (this auto adjusts indentation and makes code look exactly as of Visual Studio Code). To install theme - plugins -> search "Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme"

**OR**

**Use a different font:** I prefer

Font : "Droid Sans Mono Slashed" or "Monospaced" (You can use any that works for spacing)

Font size: 18 , Line Height 1.4 // For 14 inch screens

Font size: 14 , Line Height 1.2 // For 15.6 inch screens or larger

[image]

**OR**

**A combination of above looks beautiful.**

[image]