# Code formate break code in unnecessary code line

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using android studio and always use reformate code with 'dartfarmate' option. but it alwasy breaks the code in very unnecessary code of line which sometime disturb me while coding. what is the better solution

```
                                                Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    border: Border.all(
                                                        color: Colors.grey),
                                                    color: const Color
                                                            .fromARGB(
                                                        100, 225, 225, 225),
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius
                                                            .circular(5),
                                                  ),
                                                  margin:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          bottom: 5),
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          bottom: 8,
                                                          top: 8,
                                                          left: 8,
                                                          right: 8),
                                                  child: InputField(
                                                    text:
                                                        "detail here...",
                                                    controller:
                                                        controler,
                                                    isEditable:
                                                        true,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
```

But I expect the code should look like that

```
                                             Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                                                    color: const Color.fromARGB(100, 225, 225, 225),
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                                  ),
                                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, top: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
                                                  child: InputField(
                                                    text: "detail here...",
                                                    controller: controler,
                                                    isEditable: true,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
```

Comment: The Dart formatter by default formats code to fit within 80 columns.  If you want a different value, [you'll need to configure it to use a longer line length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65184741/).

Comment: ...or break your build function into smaller pieces (or separate widgets) so that you're nowhere near the 80 column width...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
Go to **Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Dart -> Line Length** and put and appropriate value.